# Bitrix menu количество подразделов

Tags: битрикс

Как в шаблоне bitrix:menu проверить на пустоту раздел, ну или получить количество активных подразделов?

.main.menu.php

```
`
$aMenuLinksExt = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu.sections", "", array(
    "IS_SEF" => "Y",
    "SEF_BASE_URL" => "/aura/catalog/",
    "SECTION_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_ID#/",
    "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_ID#/#ELEMENT_ID#.html",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "xmlcatalog",
    "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "Y",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "8",
    "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "3",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000"
),
    false
);
$aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinksExt, $aMenuLinks);
?>`
```

вызов menu:

`

```
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:menu",
                "main",
                Array(
                    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "main",
                    "MAX_LEVEL" => "2",
                    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "bottom",
                    "USE_EXT" => "Y",
                    "IBLOCKS_ID_DEPTH1"=>array()
                )
            );?>
```

`

Comment: В шаблоне компонента bitrix:menu не пробовали вывести $arResult? На сколько я помню у каждого пункта есть IS_PARENT вот его и анализируйте если вам достаточно ответа на вопрос имеет ли вложенные пункты.

Comment: да, выводил но он туда не попадал

Answer (score 0):

Просто переопределил компонент bitrix:menu.sections в папке local, и в нем в components в вывод добавил нижние мне параметры